# How to reset the learning rate in Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I used `tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau` to reduce the learning rate during the training and then saved the weights of my model. After I load the weights again, it seems Tensorflow remembers the last learning rate used. I tried to reset the learning rate in the optimizer's definition by`tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate = 0.001)`, however this does not work and the Tensorflow still uses the last used learning rate. Then I tried to set the minimum learning rate in `tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau`to what I want but this does not work either.
How can I change the learning rate of a model that I saved its weights?